# Export all Users in Mixpanel

Tags: python, authentication, export, user-profile, mixpanel

I tried exporting all users; but am unable to do so. I tried exporting based on the number of pages; but it did not work out.  This code only exports 1000 users and returns Error500.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/engage?project_id="

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "authorization": "Basic "
}

all_users = []

page = 0
while True:
    payload = {
        "include_all_users": True,
        "page": page
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data_json = json.loads(response.text)
        users = data_json['results']

        if not users:
            break

        all_users.extend(users)
        page += 1
    else:
        print("Error:", response.status_code)
        break

with open('exported_User_data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(all_users, jsonfile, ensure_ascii=False)

print(f"Exported {len(all_users)} users to exported_User_data.json")
```

Your help to solve this probel will grately be appreciated. Thank you!